# Python-Django: ImportError: no module named django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Im completely new to django and Ive been trying to set up an environment from here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/]. Python was already setup on my mac 
*Python 2.7.2*. I followed the instructions and setup django using

```
sudo port install py27-django
```

And also added `/etc/paths.d/macports` with

```
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/opt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin
```

But I still get the `ImportError: No module named django` message when I import django from the python shell.
I looked at this  link
[importerror: No module named django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299710/importerror-no-module-named-django) but it didnt really help much. Any help is appreciated

Comment: i would recommend using `virtualenv`

Comment: @karthikr care to elaborate?

Comment: can you post "which python" command result?

Comment: Something [like this tutorial](http://bartek.im/blog/2010/07/13/django-environment.html) Basically, install django specifically to that project. It would avoid such issues

Comment: `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` perhaps? I'm guessing you're using the system Python with the macports Django.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article... they are using virtualenv to set up the project and this fixed a lot of problems like this for me. With virtualenv, the system libraries and the libraries you need for your python project are separated, so your not mangling them together.

http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

If I may, it looks like the last path you added was pointing to a `python2.4` directory, you might need to look for `django` in a `python2.7` directory instead.

Comment: Have you got this directory? `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django` Maybe try adding that to $PATH or $PYTHONPATH. Might be a quick bodge...